# External / dual monitor not working with Mobility Radeon HD 4670 Graphics Card Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors, radeon, amd-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an [iMac 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP696?locale=en_US) with a Mobility Radeon HD 4670 graphics card and connected the 2nd monitor (Dell Inc. 27") via an Apple Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter. The second display is found in Settings > Display, but the monitor receives no signal. I have done some research and believe this is due to a missing driver for the graphics card, unfortunately, I have only been able to find outdated resources (ATI graphics section [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Intel_iMac), and these [instructions](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ubuntu-and-multiple-monitors-amd-edition/)) that suggest installing the [AMD Catalyst driver 13.1](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/ati-mobility-radeon-hd-4000-series/ati-mobility-radeon-hd-4670). However, I don't think that will compile for Ubuntu 20.04 since support goes up to kernel 3.4 (and 20.04 uses 5.4). I have seen that the AMD Catalyst (fglrx) driver is [no longer supported](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04), and am wondering what the alternative is.

Which driver do I need to install to make the second monitor work? Or is the problem something else entirely?
Thanks!